# Qt creator - simply show a working folder without creating extra Qt files

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have a makefile C/C++ project which multiple people are working on. I want to use Qt as an IDE because I really like the ease of autocompletion and links to declarations etc. However, it seems that I can't just open a working directly in Qt - I have to import or create a new project.

When creating a new project by importing an existing project, Qt creates several files (I do not want this), and when a new .c file or whatever is created outside Qt it is not shown in Qt.

Does someone have a solution to this?

Comment: You can use the 'File System' view instead of the 'Projects' one. I'm not sure how well all the features (autocompletion, ...) will work

Comment: You can configure your source control system to ignore the QT creator files AND you can always add existing files to your QT creator project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `import` your project as you are already doing.

You can ignore the files created by Qt Creator in your `.gitignore` file. Here's a nice repo for the templates: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Whenever you add a new file, you can add those using `Add Existing files...` option by right clicking on the project name.

Comment: When I do this I still have to manually add new files into the QT project whenever they are created outside of QT. Even a git pull won't add then automatically. I don't get why it simply just can't sync with the files in the working directory or function as a file explorer.

Comment: Yes. You have to do that. You can propose a change for this in `Qt Creator`. Providing a simple `Sync Project` command would do. BTW, if you add files directly using `Add New` command then they are appeared in the project listing as well as in `Version Control`.

Comment: Qt Creator needs a description of the project to autocomplete, compile and run. You probably need that project file anyway to compile it (.pro, .cmake ?). Just showing the working folder would limit very much the extra-tools you get by using an IDE. This is a price to pay.